# Convert day of year to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

In a database table (SQL Server 2012), I have dates saved in the `yyyyxxx` format, where `xxx` is the day of the year. For example `2015-08-11` is `2015223`.

How can I efficiently convert this format to `DATETIME`? How about converting `DATETIME` to this format?

Comment: The best thing you could do would be to stop storing datetime values in any datatype other than datetime.

Answer (score 6):

Get the Year part, convert to datetime + add days

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(100) = '2015223';

SELECT CAST(LEFT(@var, 4) AS DATETIME) +  CAST(RIGHT(@var, 3) AS INT) - 1;
```

Or:

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(100) = '2015223';

SELECT DATEADD(dd,CAST(RIGHT(@var, 3) AS INT)-1, CAST(LEFT(@var, 4) AS DATETIME))
```

Or if yyyyxxx is INT:

```
DECLARE @var INT = 2015223;

SELECT DATEADD(dd,(@var%1000)-1, CAST(CAST((@var/1000) AS NVARCHAR(100)) 
               AS DATETIME));
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/TRQRLE80080)**</kbd>

Comment: And if the dayofyear value might be less than 3 symbols, you can use `CAST(SUBSTRING(@var, 5, 3) AS INT)`

Comment: @Smileek I assume it will be in format yyyyxxx so '2015023'

Comment: yeah, I'm not trying to say you're wrong. Just a tiny addition in case of different situation.

Comment: Shouldn't the number of days be subtracted by 1 before adding to January 1, 2015? I get the result of 2015-08-12 instead of 2015-08-11 as was suggested in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a good answer for the first question, let's talk about the second one.

> How about converting DATETIME to this format?

[DATENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx) function can help to solve it. It's gonna look like that:

```
SELECT DATENAME(year, @var) + RIGHT('00' + DATENAME(dayofyear, @var), 3)
```