# How can I create a date in T-SQL if i have the year, and the day of the year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I create a date in T-SQL if I have the year, and the day of the year?

```
@year as int = 2017
@dayOfYear as int = 317
```

Is there something like `date(@year, 1, @dayOfYear)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331704/convert-day-of-year-to-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert day of year to datetime in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331704/convert-day-of-year-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `DATEADD` after creating the first date of `@year`:

```
DECLARE
    @year int = 2017
    , @dayOfYear int = 317

SELECT DATEADD(DAY, @dayOfYear - 1, CAST(CAST(@year AS varchar) + '0101' AS date)) [Date]
```