# How to convert four-digit Julian (yddd) to Gregorian (mm/dd/yy, etc.) in script loader?

Tags: sql, date, qlikview, date-conversion, qliksense

## The Goal

To have the data script handle the logic and conversion to a date format that is parsable/readable by a QlikSense/QlikView line graph. AKA it needs to be a normal format. (YYYYMMDD, MM/DD/YY, etc.)

## Context

- All relevant tables to the date is in one table.
- The field the date data is in is called "date", and is successfully referenced in Qliksheets by using `[Date]`
- `ddd` is the Day of the Year. `y` is the last digit of the year. The decade is assumed to be 2010s, therefore we can safely add "201" before the digit, giving you the year.

  > Examples of four-digit Julian: **9001** is **January 1st, 2019**. **9283 is October 10th, 2019**

## What I've Tried

I've been going along the route of simply adding "201" before the first digit of the provided four-digit number, and then calculating the last/next three digits of the four-digit number.

Currently, I haven't even gotten to the calculation part, as I can't even get the string concatenation to work. All my attempts have circulated around the following:

```sql
[AwesomeSheet]:
LOAD
  Right([Date], 3) as JulianDay,                         // Get day
  Left([Date], 1) as JulianYearSingleDigit,              // Get year
  201 & JulianYearSingleDigit & JulianDay as TempField   // Attempt to concatenate the numbers
  // Here be the JulianDay calculation
  Date#([TempField], 'YYYYMMDD') as FormattedDate        // Format into readable format for line graph
FROM [my-awesome-file.csv];
```

Comment: It's a number, right?  Add 2010000

Comment: Add 2010000 to what? The four-digit Julian is importing as an int

Comment: instead of concatenating 201.  But looking again, I suppose it would be adding 2010 to left([Date] ,1).  Thus 2010 plus 9 = 2019.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution is to get the year start date, add the number of days to it and convert to date:

```
date( 
  date#( '201' & left([Date], 1)  & '0101', 'YYYYMMDD') 
  -1 
  + num( mid([Date], 2,4) ) 
)
```

What the calculation is doing:

- getting the first character from the date `left([Date], 1)`
- adds `201` to format it as year number `'201' & left([Date], 1)`
- adds `0101` to it `'201' & left([Date], 1)  & '0101'`

(at this point this part will be equal to `20190101` (as string))

- `date#( '201' & left([Date], 1)  & '0101', 'YYYYMMDD')` - this will "tell" Qlik that the string inside is a date in format `YYYYMMDD`
- to the year start we'll add the days (last 3 symbols from the original string) `num( mid([Date], 2,4) )`
- cast all to date

As a result `9283` = `10/10/2019`

So your script will look like:

```
[AwesomeSheet]:
LOAD
date( 
 date#('201' & left([Date], 1)  & '0101', 'YYYYMMDD') 
 -1 
 + num( mid([Date], 2,4) ) 
) as FormattedDate
FROM [my-awesome-file.csv];
```

Thats one possible way. There might be shorter/easier way but this is on top of my head

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much! I'm toying around with some of the syntax for my particular use-case, but this idea is solid and corrects me on the right path. Thanks so much Stefan!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is a *dayOfYearToYmd* converter - this might help ["Convert day of year to datetime in SQL Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331704/convert-day-of-year-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

Also, these might help regarding the concept of *Julian* dates:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/calendar/

> Julian days simply enumerate the days and fraction which have elapsed since the start of the Julian era, which is defined as beginning at noon on Monday, 1st January of year 4713 B.C.E. in the Julian calendar.

, ie any date before the reference date has a negative value, anything after is positive, which doesn't fit with your post.

Given the above, you could declare the start of each calendar year as a reference date. :)